# My Family, My Siblings, and I

Tags: riddle, word

Thanks @starsplusplus helping me with the idea. (From his [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15570/here-is-my-family-who-am-i)). I thought of this (far fetched) answer/concept based off of his, and decided to see if anyone else could figure it out.

> I have a really large family which has been growing over the years..I don't have time to tell you about everyone but I can try to tell you a bit about some.
>
> My first sibling is a scholar. He has an interest for continuing
> learning.
>
>  My second sibling is the fun one, but can be lead to abuse.
>
>  My third sibling is smart like the first, but likes to concentrate his
> studies (on a smaller subject).
>
>  My fourth sibling likes to learn, or rather teach to learn in a
> different radical way.
>
> My fifth sibling loves to travel and loves knowing more about the
> world.
>
> My sixth sibling will be his own boss, working for himself.
>
> As for me.. I'm below the 15th sibling, who is a parent.

**Who/what is speaking, and who/what are his siblings/family?**

Make sure to explain each line for each sibling as well as the 'speaker'.

I will give some hints later on if necessary as this riddle might not be easy to understand/solve without them.

Hint #1:

> The second sibling is not directly after the first sibling and so forth. They are listed from a distinct order. "I don't have time to tell you about everyone."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from @Zikatos answer; you are

> Quantitative Finance

I believe the key is to

> take the first Stack Exchange community per distinct letter in the alphabet

Reasoning (pretty self explanatory):

*My first sibling is a scholar. He has an interest for continuing learning.*

> The first community beginning with A is Academia; definitely focused on continued learning

*My second sibling is the fun one, but can be lead to abuse.*

> The first community beginning with B is Beer; fun in moderation but alcohol abuse is no joke

*My third sibling is smart like the first, but likes to concentrate his studies (on a smaller subject).*

> The first community beginning with C is Chemistry; smart in a particular subject

*My fourth sibling likes to learn, or rather teach to learn in a different radical way.*

> The first community beginning with D is Data Science; "teaching" computers how to "learn"

*My fifth sibling loves to travel and loves knowing more about the world.*

> The first community beginning with E is Earth Science; this covers the whole world

*My sixth sibling will be his own boss, working for himself.*

> The first community beginning with F is Freelancing; become your own boss indeed!

*As for me, I'm below the 15th sibling, who's a parent.*

> The 15th letter is P (due to there being no community beginning with K).
>  The first community beginning with P is Parenting.
>  You are below it, or rather the first community beginning with Q, Quantitative Finance!
>
>  The intended answer was Puzzling, being underneath Parenting and something we are all on (a more literal me). [However the posted answer is still just as valid] - Mark N

Comment: Correct. But I now realize that my intended answer was not explicit enough :( The answer was intended to be a little 'closer to home', but you have found a valid answer.

Comment: Well done, even if I had time, I probably wouldn't find the pattern. Very nice puzzle.

Comment: @MarkN Could you put up a solution with your intended answer? I'm curious now :)

Comment: @luxmi12 I updated the last part of you answer with it. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @MarkN Ah I see! Yeah, that makes sense, I probably should have spotted that :P

Answer (score 2):

I think the sibling are

> Stack exchange communities

Ok I've tried my best, but the clues can fit multiple choices:

First sibling

> Academia - scholar + learning

Second sibling

> Anything fun can lead to abuse, I'll go with generic hobby type Stack exchange

Third sibling

> Any scientific subject for example Programmers

Fourth sibling

> Perhapse Ask Different

Fifth sibling

> Travel

Sixth sibling

> Workplace or Careers?

Me + parent

> I think the parent is Stack Overflow, because that's the largest one and on the site [Stack exchange - sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) mathematics is directly underneath.

Comment: You are close with your answer, but your guesses of the siblings can be improved (There is a pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is

> The U.S. colonies/states

My first sibling is a scholar. He has an interest for continuing learning.

> Virginia was the first colony founded. This is where the profitable Orinoco tobacco was farmed and where the farmers continued learning about the industry.

My second sibling is the fun one, but can be lead to abuse.

> Massachusetts was the second colony founded. During the Revolutionary War, it was the center of operations of the Sons of Liberty, and where many protests including the Boston Tea Party took place.

My third sibling is smart like the first, but likes to concentrate his studies (on a smaller subject).

> New Hampshire was the third colony founded. It concentrated its economy around fishing. 
>  Not a lot to go on here though.

My fourth sibling likes to learn, or rather teach to learn in a different radical way.

> The fourth colony was Maryland. It was founded by Lord Baltimore as a refuge for Catholics. At this time Catholicism was radical and Protestantism was the norm.

My fifth sibling loves to travel and loves knowing more about the world.

> Connecticut was founded by John Hooker. It was one of the leaders in shipbuilding.

My sixth sibling will be his own boss, working for himself.

> Rhode Island was founded by Roger Williams after he was kicked out of Massachusetts for his belief in separation of church and state. Rhode Island therefore can be viewed as a lone wolf of sorts.

As for me, I'm below the 15th sibling, who's a parent.

> Kentucky is the 15th state and was part of the westward expansion movement. You are Tennessee, both the 16th state and directly south of Kentucky.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't know that much about the US colonies/states..But your answer seems to fit quite well!

Comment: @MarkN Thank you. It doesn't  surprise me that it's not the right answer; it doesn't fit well in a couple places.